# Can Kentico CMS, using MVC as the templating engine, be hosted on Azure Websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, kentico

We are evaluating Kentico as a CMS option for one of our clients, and we are very partial to using Azure Websites as the production hosting platform.

From my couple days reviewing the CMS, the MVC version uses a separate website application for the MVC (user-facing) portion, and is configured (in the root web.config) to connect to the actual CMS/administration webforms application or virtual directory:

```
<add key="CMSApplicationGuid" value="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<add key="CMSApplicationName" value="Default Web Site/Kentico81_Sample_Basic"/>
<add key="CMSHashStringSalt" value="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

I have looked into their Azure solution, but I could not find any documentation on how to use MVC along with it.  The best resource I have found for development of a Kentico Azure project (even though it's written for 7.0):  http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/KenticoCMS_AzureGuide.pdf, and it seems specific to using Azure Cloud Services.

In short, are there any resources available that will guide us in the right direction for developing a Kentico MVC application for use on Azure Websites?

Answer (score 1):

From your application name I'm assuming you are using Kentico 8.1. You'll find the latest documentation for this version at:

- [docs.kentico.com](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Running+Kentico+on+Microsoft+Azure)
- [DevNet](http://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/kentico-8) - documentation guide

In a nutshell - it is possible to follow the MVC pattern within Kentico and deploy it to the Windows Azure. There is a dedicated project for that - CMSApp_MVC.csproj. This project is by default included in package deployed to Azure. If you follow the [best practices](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Developing+sites+using+the+MVC+framework) you can also use Kentico's built-in Export/Import functionality to include your MVC-specific files in the packages (allowing to transfer sites between Kentico instances - e.g. Dev and Production).

Comment: When I publish the CMSApp_MVC using Web Deploy to an Azure Website instance, it does not run, and there is no documentation available specifically on getting the MVC project to run on Azure in either of your links.  `Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' or one of its dependencies.` is what I am currently getting.  I could easily add this assembly as a reference to the MVC project, but I have a good feeling this would just be the start, which is why I was hoping this would be documented somewhere.

Comment: Note that if I publish the CMSApp project, it works without issue, but obviously doesn't include the files in the MVC project.

Comment: You have to publish CMSApp project. I'm pretty sure your MVC project would be deployed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found this documentation:  https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Publishing+web+application+projects+from+Visual+Studio, which explains how to include the other web application projects in your deployment when using web deploy.

The following lines (which were already included in the CMSApp.csproj) were actually deploying the CMSApp_MVC project files as well, when publishing the CMSApp project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn>
    CustomBinaries;
    $(PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn);
  </PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomBinaries">
  <Message Text="Collecting all contents of the bin folder." Importance="high"/>
  <ItemGroup>
    <_Binaries Include="bin\*.*" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_Binaries.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>%(Identity)</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I will continue to evaluate, and update this answer as I find more information.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  You got me started down the right path, but the above is what I was missing.  It wasn't obvious from the documentation that the MVC files were being deployed along with the CMSApp project, until I found this article.